# Why use a unique hashkey for form submissions?

Tags: algorithms, rest, ajax, validation, hashing

I have multiple forms and use AJAX to submit them. I asked my boss if he needed any specific format for the form ID and he told me to generate a unique hash and keep it in session; check it whenever the form comes back to make sure it's a valid form submission and not someone just hitting an endpoint.

What does that mean and why is it useful? How does it help me security wise?

I have read a couple of articles like [The 3 things you should know about hashCode()](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/) but I'm still not sure...

Comment: that article is about the hashCode method in java to provide correct behavior in the hash based sets

Comment: @ratchetfreak that is just for understanding, i want to know how it will be useful ?

Comment: That article is unrelated to what your boss wants, he wants you to implement a session key of sorts.

Comment: Try [This SO question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337177/security-for-a-rest-based-api) for some insight. You only need a special has that you can compare against one created during authentication so you know subsequent requests are from that user (or really, are not from anyone else)

Comment: @gbjbaanb not uncommon to have a 'latest' for the session that is computed from the previous one to avoid a replay attack.  Each step, the token is regenerated. Doesn't work for stateless requests though.

Comment: @gbjbaanb:- if user knows hash value he can easily convert that value to original value.. I think there are veryy limited hashing algorithms and if he manually tries every thing he can easily crack the code... please correct me if i m wrong ?

Comment: if user knows hash value he can easily convert that value to original value.. I think there are veryy limited hashing algorithms and if he manually tries every thing he can easily crack the code... please correct me if i m wrong ?@MichaelT

Comment: hashing algorithms are designed to be very hard to decrypt. They're called "one way encryption" for a reason. Look up SHA256 for an example of one.

Comment: @MichaelT, true, adding a timestamp and sending a new hash with every response is a good idea to keep an attacker from reusing an old hash token. This will still work with stateless requests, you're simply persisting the authentication status. Most websites work like this with persistent auth stored in a cookie (don't they?)

Comment: @gbjbaanb those that care about security do. There's the "you are who you say you are" token and there is the chain of access token (for lack of a better term - that I might be forgetting (its the use of the [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack))). The COA token is to prevent an attacker from grabbing a random request in the sequence (with both tokens) and replaying it to see what comes back.

Answer (score 4):

The technique your boss has told you to use is one of the common ways of preventing [cross site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). I think you're probably getting confused by the multiple meanings of "hash" which in this case probably refers to a secure hash (eg SHA256) rather than a hash that you might use for a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

## Why should I do it?

So we create a form, and we'll have an endpoint where that data can get submitted.

Which means anyone can submit data there and see what happens.

So we need to validate on two things:

1. that it's being submitted by a user (which .NET will handle for us), and
2. that they're submitting data via a requested form and not just willy-nilly

So the submit button needs a validation hash that gets passed back with the form, then we compare that to the value we stored in the user's session (on the server) when we created the form.

If they match, we process the data, otherwise we throw an error.

## Way to do it:

Write a function which converts genrated id and creates hash for it.

Get the form, decrypt the hash to get the original ID, compare them with the id stored in session, and voila.